# Qt3 vs Qt5 programming syntax

Tags: qt, syntax, qt5, qt3

Hi I'm teaching myself Qt based on Qt 5.7.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit), Qt Creator 4.1.0 - community edition.  I am using an book, "Programming with Qt, 2nd Edition" by Matthias Kalle Dalheimer which focuses on QT3.  One of the exercises is to have a slider which uses the LCD number display.  There are also two buttons (add, subtract) to change the slider and LCD display.  I was not able to get the book code to work because there have been major syntax changes.

I was able to get my code to work using the Qt designer but I want to do it without that as well.  How can I do that?  I was thinking of using events but I couldn't figure out the syntax.

Here is the snippets from the book.

```
QObject::connect(decrement, SIGNAL(clicked()), myslider, SLOT(subtractStep()));
QObject::connect(increment, SIGNAL(clicked()), myslider, SLOT(addStep()));
```

These are the error messages from the console for my code below in main.cpp:
"QObject::connect: No such slot QSlider::SingleStep()in ..\ProgrammingQt\main.cpp:31
QObject::connect: No such signal QSlider::triggerAction(SliderSingleStepAdd) in ..\ProgrammingQt\main.cpp:32"

Here is my code without the ui. - main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qslider.h>
#include <qlcdnumber.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qstring.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setGeometry(400, 300, 170, 150);

    QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, widget);
    slider->setGeometry(10, 10, 150,30);

    QLCDNumber *lcd = new QLCDNumber(2, widget);
    lcd->setGeometry(60, 50, 50, 50);
    lcd->display(1);

    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    QPushButton *addBtn = new QPushButton("ADD ONE", widget);
    addBtn->setGeometry(10, 110, 50, 30);
    //QObject::connect(addBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), slider, SLOT(SliderSingleStepAdd()));
    //QObject::connect(addBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), slider, SLOT(SingleStep()));
    //QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(triggerAction(SliderSingleStepAdd)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    QPushButton *minusBtn = new QPushButton("MINUS ONE", widget);
    minusBtn->setGeometry(100, 110, 60, 30);
   //  QObject::connect(minusBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), slider, SLOT    (SliderSingleStepSub()));

    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    widget->setWindowTitle("LCD Number");
    widget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the code using the Qt Designer:  mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_slider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->lcd->display(value);
}

void MainWindow::on_addBtn_clicked()
{
    int incVal = ui->slider->value();
    incVal++;
    ui->slider->setValue(incVal);
    ui->lcd->display(incVal);
}

void MainWindow::on_minusBtn_clicked()
{
    int decVal = ui->slider->value();
    decVal--;
    ui->slider->setValue(decVal);
    ui->lcd->display(decVal);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QLCDNumber>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

   private slots:

   void on_slider_valueChanged(int value);

   void on_addBtn_clicked();
   void on_minusBtn_clicked();

 private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Qt3 was so different from Qt4 and Qt5, that it's probably not very useful trying to use Qt3 book here... Qt4 book would work because Qt5 is almost source-compatible with Qt4. But Qt5 introduces new, superior ways of doing many things, so your time would be better spent learning from Qt5 material.

Comment: unfortunately there weren't any newer QT books in my local libraries.

Comment: Qt has great online documentation available for Qt 5 and Qt 4

Comment: Try googling "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 pdf" (not sure if what Google finds with that is legit, download on your own discretion). And check out https://wiki.qt.io/Books and consider suggesting your library to get some fresher material for Qt5 (or buy some yourself, if that's an option, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The slots `SliderSingleStepAdd`, `SingleStep` or `SliderSingleStepSub` are not found because there are not defined in the object `slider`.

[According](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) to the documentation,

> All classes that inherit from QObject or one of its subclasses (e.g.,
>   QWidget) can contain signals and slots.

So you need a class where you must implement your required signals and slots.

For example, your main should be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qslider.h>
#include <qlcdnumber.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qstring.h>
#include <myclass.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyClass myClass;

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setGeometry(400, 300, 170, 150);

    QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, widget);
    slider->setGeometry(10, 10, 150,30);

    QLCDNumber *lcd = new QLCDNumber(2, widget);
    lcd->setGeometry(60, 50, 50, 50);
    lcd->display(1);

    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    QPushButton *addBtn = new QPushButton("ADD ONE", widget);
    addBtn->setGeometry(10, 110, 50, 30);
    QObject::connect(addBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &myClass, SLOT(SliderSingleStepAdd()));
    QObject::connect(addBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &myClass, SLOT(SingleStep()));
    // QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(triggerAction(SliderSingleStepAdd)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    QPushButton *minusBtn = new QPushButton("MINUS ONE", widget);
    minusBtn->setGeometry(100, 110, 60, 30);
    QObject::connect(minusBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &myClass, SLOT(SliderSingleStepSub()));

    QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));

    widget->setWindowTitle("LCD Number");
    widget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And you should have a class like the following one:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(): QObject() {}
    virtual ~MyClass() {}

   public slots:
    void SliderSingleStepAdd ()
    {
        std::cout << "SliderSingleStepAdd" << std::endl;
    }

    void SingleStep ()
    {
        std::cout << "SingleStep" << std::endl;
    }

    void SliderSingleStepSub ()
    {
        std::cout << "SliderSingleStepSub" << std::endl;
    }

};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

In my opinion, all your objects (slider, lcd and buttons) should be in a class that inherits from `QWidget` so you can connect those objects. This should be also necessary in case of the following connect:

```
QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(triggerAction(SliderSingleStepAdd)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));
```